# How to properly render letters with diacritics in MathJax?

Tags: mathjax

I'm  trying to render the word **කැකි** in MathJax inside Jupyter-lab with the following code but I get the result as shown in the photo where diacritics aren't properly placed. How can I solve this issue?

```
$$
\unicode[UN-Abhaya]{x0d9a}\unicode[UN-Abhaya]{x0dd0}\unicode[UN-Abhaya]{x0d9a}\unicode[UN-Abhaya]{x0dd2}
$$
```

[The result I get from the first code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJncf.png)

```
$$
\text{කැකි}
$$
```

gives the same result with a different font which looks worse.

[The result I get from the second code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1naC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$$
\style{font-family: UN-Abhaya}{\text{කැකි}}
$$$
```

and see if that works better for you.

Comment: It does. Thank You. You wouldn't mind telling me why would you?

Comment: Maybe a link to a documentation or something?

Comment: It sets the font to use for the text, as you were doing with the individual `\unicode` commands via the '[UN-Abhaya]` option.  The default font for characters not in MathJax's font, like the ones you are using) apparently has a visible character for some of the combining characters you are using.  If you control the website, you could change the MathJax configuration to change to the UN-Abhaya font for text automatically.